# How to tell if two QPushButtons have been pressed (Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qpushbutton

I need to call a member function when both of my QPushButtons have been pressed.  I cannot find a way to keep track of if they have been pressed.

I call a function when either of the buttons are clicked using ...clicked.connect(func) and within that function I have tried to: 1) return a value, 2) update a member variable. Below I have shown how I tried to create and update member variable and use a conditional to see if both variables were true so that I could call my next function.

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MorphingApp, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.startIm = None
    self.endIm = None

    self.initialState()


def initialState(self):

    self.btn_loadStart.clicked.connect(self.loadImageS)
    self.btn_loadEnd.clicked.connect(self.loadImageE)

    if(self.startIm is True and self.endIm is True):
        self.loadedState()


def initialState(self):
    self.startIm = True


def loadImageE(self):
    self.endIm = True
```

My functions of course do things, but I removed parts that were irrelevant.   When I run the GUI I am able to load the images but the function that is supposed to be called after both buttons have been pushed is not called.  I know this because the state of the GUI is not changing as I intend.

This is my first time posting a question so let me know how to improve :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple True/False flag to check if the button has been pressed at least once. Both buttons start with the flag set to False, so we can set that up in the init method.

Then place the code that checks to see if both buttons have been pressed inside the functions connected to them. Finally, simply call the respective "final" function if the check passes.

This is an example using two generic buttons:

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MorphingApp, self).__init__(parent)
    self.btn_01_pressed = False
    self.btn_02_pressed = False
    self.set_buttons()

def set_buttons(self):
    self.btn_01.clicked.connect(self.check01)
    self.btn_02.clicked.connect(self.check02)

def check01(self):
    self.btn_01_pressed = True
    if self.btn_01_pressed is True and self.btn_02_pressed is True:
        self.call_final_function()

def check02(self):
    self.btn_02_pressed = True
    if self.btn_01_pressed is True and self.btn_02_pressed is True:
        self.call_final_function()

def call_final_function(self):
    # do something great here
```

Like in your post I've ommited some parts necessary for the actual code (like creating the `QPushButton` widgets), but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MorphingApp, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.startIm = False
    self.endIm = False

    self.btn_loadStart.clicked.connect(self.loadImageS)
    self.btn_loadEnd.clicked.connect(self.loadImageE)


def loadImageS(self):
    self.startIm = True

    if self.startIm and self.endIm:
        self.loadedState()


def loadImageE(self):
    self.endIm = True

    if self.startIm and self.endIm:
       self.loadedState()
```